# How do you conditionally combine filters using the MongoDB C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Consider the following filter:

```
var builder = Builders<Product>.Filter;

var filter = builder.Gte(i => i.Price, criteria.MinPrice) &
                            builder.Lte(i => i.Price, criteria.MaxPrice);
if (0 != criteria.CategoryId)
//Combine the following filter with the previous filter. How??
                var criteriaFilter = builder.Eq(i => i.CategoryId, criteria.CategoryId);
```

How do I combine the *criteriaFilter* and *filter*?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
if (criteria.CategoryId != 0)
{
    var criteriaFilter = builder.Eq(i => i.CategoryId, criteria.CategoryId);
    filter = filter & criteriaFilter;
}
```

Comment: How does this merge the two filters?

Comment: @Guerrilla I know this is a bit late, but just came across this. `&` operator override is defined to do this: `return new AndFilterDefinition<TDocument>(new[] { lhs, rhs });` (driver version 2.18.0).